# Postman/Docgen documentation doesn't show the response of endpoints

Tags: node.js, express, postman, documentation-generation

I created a node application and before it is deployed, I want to create an API documentation. For that I used postman and docgen. The created documentation works fine. It displays the endpoint, header and body. But it doesn't show the response of any of these endpoints. [image: This is the register endpoint]

How can I display the response of these endpoints in my documentation??

Comment: The screen you have shared is not Postman documentation anyway.

Comment: This is a docgen html file which was created with exported postman json file.

Comment: The [page on the project repo](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/docgen) seems to have this feature. But "Saving example" in postman doesn't add the reponse into the output doc. Maybe create an issue in the project itself?

Comment: Alright, I found the solution. You just need to save the response as example. And then export the docs with docgen. This will automatically include the response

Comment: You can save response in postman collection, and if the response is saved then the docgen will show the responses in response section